# jquery shadow box in rails app

Tags: jquery, shadowbox

I am trying to integrate `jQuery shadowbox`. So I need to know whether it can done for the `td`'s. As per the documentation of **shadowbox**, the `rel=shadowbox` has to be added for **links**.

But in my case I have `table` instead of **links**. So when the user clicks on any `td`'s a **shadowbox** should open. Is it possbile with **shadowbox**?

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the [docs](http://www.shadowbox-js.com/usage.html):

```
Shadowbox.init({
    // skip the automatic setup again, we do this later manually
    skipSetup: true
});

window.onload = function() {

    // set up all anchor elements with a "movie" class to work with Shadowbox
    Shadowbox.setup("a.movie", {
        gallery:            "My Movies",
        autoplayMovies:     true
    });

};​
```

In your case, use `td.your_class` instead of `a.movie`.

EDIT:
I don't know what should be the content but you can do this:

```
Shadowbox.init({
    skipSetup: true
});

$('table td').click(function(e) { // when td is clicked..
    Shadowbox.open({
        content: '<p>Put your content here.</p>',
        player: 'html',
    title: 'My shadowbox'
    });​
});
```

Note the `player` and `content`.

Comment: so what input will I provide for the gallery option?? What I basically need is to show a form inside the shadowbox.